# Virtual Machine Administrator Login error (azure vm)

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have followed following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux

and ran these commands

az vm extension set 
--publisher Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory 
--name AADSSHLoginForLinux 
--resource-group AzureADLinuxVM 
--vm-name myVM

username=$(az account show --query user.name --output tsv)
vm=$(az vm show --resource-group AzureADLinuxVM --name myVM --query id -o tsv)

az role assignment create 
--role "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" 
--assignee $username 
--scope $vm

but when I am trying to login using

ssh -l email ip

it throws error as "permission denied (public key)" can someone help me through this?